# No devuelve valor del input en php XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente formulario

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-grup col-sm-6">
        <label>Nombre Visita:</label>
        <br>
        <select id="equipo-select" class="form-control" name="nombre_v">
            <option disabled selected>Selecciona un equipo</option>
            <?php foreach($equipos as $i){  ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i->id_equi; ?>">
                    <?php echo $i->nombre; ?>
                </option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-grup col-sm-6">
        <label>ID:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="logo_v" id="logo-select" class="form-control" disabled>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getEquiposLista() {
        var equipo_select = document.getElementById("equipo-select");

        var equipo_id = equipo_select.options[equipo_select.selectedIndex].value;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'equipos.php?id_equi=' + equipo_id;
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var text = xhr.responseText;
                logo_select.innerHTML = text;
                logo_select.style.display = 'inline';
                logo_select.value
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }

    function getLogoLista() {
        xhr.send();
    }

    var equipo_select = document.getElementById("equipo-select");
    equipo_select.addEventListener("change", getEquiposLista);

    var logo_select = document.getElementById("logo-select");
    logo_select.addEventListener("change", getLogoLista);


</script>
```

El problema es cuando quiero guardar me da el siguiente error

Notice: Undefined index: logo_v in C:...\agregar.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: logo_c in C:...\agregar.php on line 13

Comment: Los errores que comentas, se encuentran en `agregar.php` deberías de subir ese fichero. Y si se trata del que has subido, indicalo e indica también las líneas 12 y 13 de los errores, ya que nosotros no tenemos referencias de cuales son sino publicas todo el código.

Comment: en el archivo agregar es a donde manda el formulario y ahí solo están los $_POST y después la consulta de guardar. El problema es que recibo solo los valores  de los campos logo_c y logo_v, que son los unicos que estoy recibiendo con ajax.